# Using values from an ArrayList in a where clause without loads of queries?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist

I'm trying to accomplish basically this:

```
Select * FROM x WHERE id != for(int i : arraylist)
```

So basically I have an arraylist with say 10 ids, I want the sql not to return any of the rows that have an ID the same as in my arraylist, and I'd rather not do it with like 10 queries. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the SQL `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE id NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, etc. )
```

Answer (score 1):

in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE id not in ( list of value ) // i.e. 'A', 'B', ...
```

Pay attention:
You can execute this statement only if yuo array has been filled.

If you have an array with no items NOT IN can cause problems.

So, you must check your condition before put NOT IN clause.